# The term Get-PnPAzureADUser is not recognized as the name of a Cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a PnP Power shell script, but it is raising this error:-

```
The term Get-PnPAzureADUser is not recognized as the name of a Cmdlet
```

any advice?
Thanks

Comment: The error usually occurs if the **Pnp PowerShell** module is not installed. Install the module by running `Install-ModulePnP.Powershell` and check whether the module is installed by running `Get-InstalledModule -Name pnp*`. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/ZmvNvUj.png). If still the issue persists re-install the module

Comment: I had the same error. When I ran `Get-InstalledModule -Name pnp*` it said it was installed. I had to update to Powershell7 to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs, if the **Pnp PowerShell** module is not being installed in the PowerShell.

**To resolve the error, make sure to install the module like below:**

```
Install-Module PnP.Powershell
Get-InstalledModule -Name pnp*
```

[image]

[image]

After installing the PnP module, I am able to execute `Get-PnPAzureADUser` successfully like below:

[image]

If still the issue persists, re-install the PnP PowerShell module.